# Design pattern with singleton in package

Tags: go

I'm still not an expert in golang and try to understand and learn best practice

How to initialize a singleton in a package and make it thread safe so there will ONLY be one instance even if the package is imported multiple times in different files

Now the instance `sessions` is initiated in the main, but then I have to pass it around. How to initiate the instance `sessions` inside the package `sess` so it will be a global variable or something inside the package?

I want it to be a private variable inside the package `sess`

```
package main

func main(){
    sessions := sess.Init()
}
```

`sess` module

```
package sess

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type pool struct {
    lock        sync.RWMutex
    sessions    map[string]*session
}

func Init() *pool {
    p := &pool{
        sessions:   map[string]*session{},
    }
        
    return p
}

func (p *pool) Set(sid string, s *session){
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    
    p.sessions[sid] = s
}

func (p *pool) Get(sid string) (*session, bool){
    p.lock.RLock()
    defer p.lock.RUnlock()
    
    s, ok := p.sessions[sid]
    return s, ok
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and initialize an [exported](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) package-level variable with the singleton.  There is a single initialized instance of each package-level variable, not one instance or initialization for each import.

```
package sess

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type pool struct {
    lock        sync.RWMutex
    sessions    map[string]*session
}

var Pool = &pool{sessions: map[string]*session{}}

func (p *pool) Set(sid string, s *session){
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()
    
    p.sessions[sid] = s
}

func (p *pool) Get(sid string) (*session, bool){
    p.lock.RLock()
    defer p.lock.RUnlock()
    
    s, ok := p.sessions[sid]
    return s, ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If some other package depends on the `pool` you can just inject it.
For example ([Go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/5xO64DHmfVQ)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// Interfaces.
// As Go implements duck-typing they can be located in separate package to avoid circular dependencies
type Session interface {
    ID() uint64
    Username() string
}

type SessionPool interface {
    Set(sid string, s Session)
    Get(sid string) (Session, bool)
}

// structs

// session and pool struct should be located in the same package
// --- session
type session struct {
    sessionID uint64
    username  string
}

func (s *session) ID() uint64 {
    return s.sessionID
}

func (s *session) Username() string {
    return s.username
}

// --- pool
type pool struct {
    lock     sync.RWMutex
    sessions map[string]*session
}

func NewSessionPool() *pool {
    p := &pool{
        sessions: make(map[string]*session),
    }

    return p
}

func (p *pool) Set(sid string, s Session) {
    p.lock.Lock()
    defer p.lock.Unlock()

    p.sessions[sid] = &session{s.ID(), s.Username()}
}

func (p *pool) Get(sid string) (Session, bool) {
    p.lock.RLock()
    defer p.lock.RUnlock()

    s, ok := p.sessions[sid]
    return s, ok
}

//  SessionPoolInfo located in different package and depends on SessionPool
// --- SessionPoolInfo
type SessionPoolInfo struct {
    sessionPool SessionPool
}

func NewSessionPoolInfo(sp SessionPool) *SessionPoolInfo {
    return &SessionPoolInfo{
        sessionPool: sp,
    }
}

func (si *SessionPoolInfo) PrintInfo(sid string) {
    if session, ok := si.sessionPool.Get(sid); ok {
        fmt.Printf("Session ID: %d, Username: %s\n", session.ID(), session.Username())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("session not found (ID: %s)\n", sid)
    }
}

func main() {
    sp := NewSessionPool()
    s := &session{
        sessionID: 1,
        username:  "John Doe",
    }
    sp.Set("1", s)

    spi := NewSessionPoolInfo(sp)
    spi.PrintInfo("1")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use the `sync.Once` type to ensure this. [sync.Once](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Once) is an object that will perform exactly one action.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
.
.
.
var p *pool
var once sync.Once
.
.
.
// Pool returns default pool instance
// it initialised the pool if not initilaised
func Pool() *pool {
    once.Do(func() {
        p = &pool{
            sessions: map[string]*session{},
        }
    })
    return p
}
```

Here is a [link](https://play.golang.com/p/joPdvxQFJ67) to playground

Answer (score 0):

First you probably don't want a singleton, it's more likely you want to create the struct once and pass it along or better pass an interface representing the behavior you want.  That said you can use the `init()` func to initialize singletons

```
type Singleton struct {
    Message string
}

var MyGlobalStruct *Singleton

func init() {
    MyGlobalStruct = &Singleton{Message: "hello world"}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(MyGlobalStruct.Message)
}
```

Comment: I want it to be a global inside the package `sess`. Otherwise I have to pass the variable each time I call a function

Comment: Or more correct a private variable in package `sess`